# Keep SwipeRefreshLayout displayed until service is finished running

Tags: android

So right now I have swipe to refresh in my app. When it is activated, a service which runs an async background task is executed. Problem is, the swipe to refresh indicator disappears immediately. How do I keep it displayed (and update my recycler view) when the service has finished running?
Here is some code:

```
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.StatusbarColor,R.color.Accent);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                callRefreshService();

            }
        });
```

Here is the callRefreshService method:

```
public void callRefreshService() {
        try{
            Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateScoresService.class);
            startService(service);
        }
        finally {
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(db.getTracked());
            db.closeDB();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I tried using try and finally but that doesn't help.

Comment: Do you need to do that in a service? I mean why don't you just use an `AsyncTask` and stop refreshing the view in `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: The service is also for refresh data while the app isn't open. I was doing what you mentioned before but I'd like to consolidate the code to not have to manage 2 almost identical sets of code.

Answer (score 1):

`startService(Intent)` does not block, it returns immediately.

You got two options:

1. Ditch the Service for AsyncTask
2. Allow the Service to communicate with your Activity

Choose 1 for something trivial like a one-off `JSON` download task. Call `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` in the `onPostExecute (Result result)` block.

Choose 2 if you got something complex setup already. 
Communication between Activity and Service is slightly complicated, what you need is a [bind service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). If you want something simple, you can look take a look at event bus, it decouple things quite nicely.

Here are some implementations of an event bus:

- [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)
- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: The service is also for refresh data while the app isn't open. I was doing what you mentioned before with the async task but I'd like to consolidate the code to not have to manage 2 almost identical sets of code.

Comment: Is there a way for me to call a method in my MainActivity from my service?

Comment: To your first comment: how about defining a static method and call it in your async task and service?

Comment: If you want to call a method from the service, you need something like AIDL or a `Messenger`, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your activity

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // stop refreshing the layout
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
};
```

register it to your activity inside `onResume()` to listen to some `Intenet` and unregister it inside `onPause()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // register the receiver
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.app.STOP_REFRESH"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // unregister the receiver
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

then inside your `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute()` send the message with the `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.STOP_REFRESH");
// you can also add extras to this intent
// intent.putExtra("key", value);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```